# qTip2 - remotipart and rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, qtip2

I am using `remotipart` in rails 3.1, It works perfectly fine on all kind of forms perfectly fine. But there is an issue in my scenario,

What i am doing is that i have a `remote link` which request to the `new` action which displays the form in a `qTip2 modal tip`, On that form i have a file filed.

I have bound `ajax:beforeSend.rails` event which `hides` the tooltip, So now the situation is if i hide the `tooltip` remote call do not work, if i don't hide the tooltip it works perfectly fine.

What i figured out is when tooltip is hidden , means the form has a `display:none`  remote ajax calls do not work. Is it the scenario? and how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, i have a global deletegate method bind to qTip, hide event, which was causing to remove tooltip from doom.

Fixed that issue and every thing works perfectly fine now.